# Missing DataProfiling view from AIRFLOW -UI

Tags: airflow

Missing Data Profiling view when used FAB-Security with RBAC.

I have created users using airflow create_users 
even the users have admin privileges data profiling view is not available on UI any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the breaking changes section in [Updating Airflow and backwards-incompatible](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/UPDATING.md#breaking-changes) the "new" webserver wont be supporting every feature of the old webserver.

> Due to security concerns, the new webserver will no longer support the features in the Data Profiling menu of old UI, including Ad Hoc Query, Charts, and Known Events.

Comment: Hi Tomme , Thanks for comment I am using AIRFLOW version : 1.10.2 , If I roll back Flask-AppBuilder to Flask-Admin will that be ok or do I need to  install a lower airflow version

Comment: The "old" web server is still in 1.10.2 I believe, setting `rbac` to `False` in `airflow.cfg` (which will switch from AppBuilder to Admin) should solve it for you (though obviously you will not have RBAC anymore).

Comment: Thanks for the information, with this new UI, i feel it run more smoothy.

Comment: hi @Tomme, is it by any chance possible to do Ad Hoq query under Data Profiling, even after enabling RBAC. I mean changing in airflow code or something like that.